# How to calculate graduation year based on birthdate

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I calculate graduation year based on birth date? Such that if my birthday was April 1992, I'd graduate in 2010 vs October 1992 I'd graduate in 2011.

Also, this is assuming the person starts school normally and graduates at a normal rate, based on the US education system, where school starts early September and ends early June.

Comment: This probably varies by region according to the law.

Comment: This also depends on the person, there's plenty of examples of people that graduate way earlier or way later.

Comment: What is the cut-off month for enrollment purposes? Something between April and October, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on your country's  education system. For an example:

In Japan Graduate school starts at age of 23

Graduate school -Master - age 23-24

Graduate school -PhD - age 26-27